# How to put one table on one disk and anther table on another (a ramdisk)?

Tags: postgresql, tablespaces

I need to build a database with one table stored on one disk and anther table stored on a different disk (a ramdisk).

Is it possible to do it?

As far as I know, using two separate databases, one for each disk, is not efficient.

I am considering PostgreSQL, but other options can be ok. The reason I want to use a ramdisk is to deal with non critical data that can be deleted at any time, to avoid SSD wearing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not done it but, if not mistaken, it can be easily accomplished with [tablespaces](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/manage-ag-tablespaces.html).

Let us know how it went.

Comment: Yes, it seems to be the right solution.